# Can a piece of code know whether it's running in the context of a Rails request or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible for a piece of Ruby code to know whether it's being run in the context of a Ruby on Rails request or not (for example, as a background job or a rake task)?

Comment: Why not pass this information directly?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel because I would have to pass down this information down a lot of methods and it would be rather ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to distinguish if something is executed in rake task by the value or presence of special global variables:

```
task :tryout do
  if File.basename($0) == 'rake'
    puts 'It is a rake task.'
  end
end
```

In previous snippet one relies on the `$0` path to executable ending with `rake`. In previous Rails versions there was a `$rails_rake_task` variable, but in my current env it was not defined (
I've tried that on Rails 4).

In Rails controller, you can check if there was a request from the user with `$CGI_ENV` global variable or `ActionDispach::Request` request object.

Comment: Checking for a rake task wouldn't work for me as the code can be run in a variety of environments and my problem is doing something different (faster) when it's in a Rails request.

Comment: It is just an example of using already defined global variables for your purpose. What do you mean by 'doing something faster'? Checking already defined global variable in memory isn't fast enough?